# Getting negative predictions with LinearRegressionWithSGD in spark 1.6

Tags: apache-spark, linear-regression, apache-spark-mllib

```
package ml_prj_01_01

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LinearRegressionWithSGD

object linear_02 {

  def par1(x: String): Array[Double]={
    val a= x.split(",")
    val b=a(0).toDouble
    val c=a(1).toDouble
    val d=a(2).toDouble
    val e=a(3).toDouble
    val f=a(4).toDouble
    val g=a(5).toDouble
    val h=a(6).toDouble
    val i=a(7).toDouble
    val j=a(8).toDouble
    val k=a(9).toDouble
    val l=a(10).toDouble


    return Array(b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l)
  }

  def par2(x: Array[Double]): LabeledPoint={
    return new

  LabeledPoint(x(0),Vectors.dense(x(1),x(2),x(3)
  ,x(4),x(5),x(6),x(7),x(8),x( 
  9),x(10)) )

  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
  val conf = new 
  SparkConf().setAppName("linear_02").setMaster("local[*]")
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)



  val file = sc.textFile("/home/user/Downloads/Prj_files/house price 
  linear_reg/housedata(linear regression)/pricing_finalized")


  val todouble= file.map(x=> par1(x))
  val tolp= todouble.map(x=> par2(x))


  val training= tolp.filter(x=> x.features(2) >900)
  val testing= tolp.filter(x=> x.features(2) <=900)



  val model= 
  LinearRegressionWithSGD.train(training,50,0.0000006,1.0)
  val predictions= testing.map(x=> 
  (x.label,model.predict(x.features)) )

  predictions.take(10).foreach(println)


}

}
```

In above code I am getting the predictions only as negative.Taking up features and label to predict the pricing gives the negative output which isn't possible. Due to this even the mean square error and root mean square errors couldn't be calculated.

column names respective to file are :- 
 pricing,bedrooms,bathroom,sqft_living,sqft_lot,floors,waterfront,view,condition,sqft_above,sqft_basement

The dataset file is provided at the link below:

[dataset_file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AoW_gpCCTqf2in4m8e_RAIUrDimv)

Comment: It is possible to get negative predictions when you use stochastic gradient descent because It will depend on the initial weights you start with, the learning size and the number of epochs. Try to play with the parameter `Vector` of `LinearRegressionWithSGD` which controls the initial coefficients

Comment: I did not get you "play with parameter Vector" ? do you mean to change/modify the training set

Comment: No, I meant that you should provide explicit initial weights to your linear regresion by using the parameter `Vector` https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/regression/LinearRegressionWithSGD.html , for example if your linear regression equation has two coefficients then add `DenseVector(Array(0.5, 0.5))` where your initial coefficients are given by `Array(0.5,0.5)`, or any initial weights you want (or set a seed and draw those coeficients from a normal distribution)

Comment: "val model= LinearRegressionWithSGD.train(training,80,0.0000006,1.0,Vectors.dense(0.0,0.2,0.1,0.0,0.0,0.1,0.4,0.3,0.0,0.0))" is it fine?

Comment: I think that will yield an error. Let me try another example in my computer.

Comment: above line executes but output doesn't shows any change

Comment: I'm using Spark 1.6 and I managed to set the initial weights by using the method `run`, have a look here https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LinearRegressionWithSGD so I type `val new regression=new LinearRegressionWithSGD()` and then `regression.run(myData,initialWeights=Vectors.dense(...))`, however I get an error when I use `train`

Comment: how we print output when we use regression in this way?

Comment: I used `regression.run(myData,initialWeights=Vectors.dense(...)).predict(myNewData)` to get new predictions. It's a bit strange because it should be possible to set the initial weights in your situation and also I shouldn't get an error when I try `train` like yours. Also I can't find a method which displays the coefficients obtained, that way you can verify why you get negative predictions

Comment: using in such way show error in my program for predict method overload

Comment: check the required format of the new data which you want to predict, I think it should be `Vectors.dense` instead of `LabeledPoint`

Comment: yes it is (label,vectors.dense). as the test data is derived from labeled data.

Comment: Try to predict one single observation in the format `Vectors.dense`, apply `predict`, then vary the initial weights and try again `predict`, you should see a different prediction. That shows that the initial weights somehow determines the output

Comment: It shouldn't be `LabeledPoint` for predict. The implementation is a bit messy...